# How to print a pyramid of full pyramids?

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns

I'm a newbie programmer, and we were recently tasked with printing a full pyramid of asterisks with the number of rows being based on the input, then printing a pyramid of those pyramids.

Basically the output I'm expecting when the user inputs `Number of Rows: 4` is:

```
                     *
                    ***
                   *****
                  *******
               *     *     *
              ***   ***   ***
             ***** ***** *****
            *******************
         *     *     *     *     *
        ***   ***   ***   ***   ***
       ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
      *******************************
   *     *     *     *     *     *     *
  ***   ***   ***   ***   ***   ***   ***
 ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
*******************************************
```

This is the best that I could work on using looping.

```
rowInput = int(input("Number of Rows: "))
rowCount = 0
min = rowInput
max = rowInput

while (rowCount < rowInput):
  digit = 1
  while (digit < min): 
    print(end=" ")
    digit += 1
  while (digit >= min and digit <= max):
    print(end="*")
    digit += 1
    
  print()
  min -= 1
  max += 1
  rowCount += 1
```

Input:

```
Number of Rows: 4
```

Output:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

I think that it could work with another loop on top, but I can't think of a viable way to increment the spaces between two triangles. Are there any other options?

Comment: some python hints that can help: you can multiply strings `3*'*'` returns `'***'`, works with spaces too.  and the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) type will make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a list of lines to print using a nested list comprehension but it's a bit convoluted.

```
rows = 4

lines = [" "*(rows-r//2-1)*(2*rows-1) +  f"{'*'*i:^{2*rows-1}}"*r
         for r in range(1,2*rows+1,2)
         for i in range(1,2*rows+1,2)]

print(*lines,sep='\n')

                        *   
                       ***  
                      ***** 
                     *******
                 *      *      *   
                ***    ***    ***  
               *****  *****  ***** 
              *********************
          *      *      *      *      *   
         ***    ***    ***    ***    ***  
        *****  *****  *****  *****  ***** 
       ***********************************
   *      *      *      *      *      *      *   
  ***    ***    ***    ***    ***    ***    ***  
 *****  *****  *****  *****  *****  *****  ***** 
*************************************************
```

For easier to understand code, for-loops are probably better:

```
rows = 4

width = 2*rows-1                          # width of one pyramid
for r in range(1,rows+1):                 # row with r pyramids
    indent = " "*(rows-r)*width           # indent pyramids
    for p in range(rows):                 # pyramid lines 
        fill = "*"*(2*p+1)                # filled width/stars for line
        print(indent+(2*r-1)*f"{fill:^{width}}") # repeated pyramid stars
```

Another good way to approach this is to decompose the problem into smaller parts that you implement in individual functions.  Combining the functions that perform small tasks makes it easier to implement and test your solution:

```
# produce lines for one pyramid
def pyramid(n):
    return [f"{'*'*r:^{2*n-1}}" for r in range(1,2*n+1,2)]

# combine pyramids horizontally
def pyramidRow(count,n): 
    return [count*line for line in pyramid(n)]

width = 2*rows-1                          # width of one pyramid
for r in range(1,rows+1):                 # row of r pyramids
    indent = " "*width*(rows-r)           # indent pyramids 
    for line in pyramidRow(2*r-1,rows):   # print repeated pyramids
        print(indent+line)
```

Testing:

```
for line in pyramid(4): print(line)

   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******

for line in pyramidRow(3,4): print(line)

   *      *      *   
  ***    ***    ***  
 *****  *****  ***** 
*********************
```

Comment: `(2*r-1)*f"{fill:^{width}}`

Might I ask what does this part of the code means?

Comment: `2*r-1` is the number of pyramids on row `r`.  This number is multiplied by the spaces+stars+spaces string of one pyramid line to essentially print it multiple times horizontally.  The `f"{fill:^{width}}"` part is that spaces+stars+spaces string built using Python's format-string convention where `fill` is the repeated stars needed for pyramids on that line and `:^{width}` specifies to center these stars in a fixed width by adding spaces on each side.

Comment: Another nice post of using the string `format`.